# JQuery keypress special buttons issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, onkeypress

I am working about press the key of insert on the my page , but i have any error about keycode of insert.

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
     var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
     console.log(code);
     if(code===45){
          alert("Insert Clicked");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this is my code . When i clicked some key it work fine , but when i press insert,tab,del,backspace,shift it doesn't work. There is any mistake ? I didn't find any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keydown` with `e.preventDefault();`:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   console.log(code);
   if(code == 45) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       alert("Insert Clicked");
   }
});
```

Comment: It is not  work sir. I want to write function on insert key.

Comment: Modified my answer.

Comment: I dont have rep :) i cant voting

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  console.log(code);
  if(code===45){
    alert("Insert Clicked");
  }
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t5458erd/